# How unmanaged object is destroyed/collected in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, dispose

Here is a scenario:
There is a class defined in managed c++ dll and used in C# project.

```
public ref class AClass {
// ......
  XParameters m_oParams;
  property XParameters^ Parameters {
           XParameters^ get() { return m_oParams; }
        }

}
```

XParameters is another managed c++-defined class visible to C# side.

C# code looks like this:

```
var aClass = new AClass();
var oParams = aClass.Parameters;
aClass = null;
```

Actually I want to guarantee that `oParams` becomes null after I assign null to the `aClass` object itself.
Is there a way to do it?

What exactly happens when `aClass = null` called?

Comment: Note that your sample shows no "unmanaged" objects.

Comment: Nothing happens.  Such a statement is always removed by the jitter optimizer since it has no use.  If you want it null then you'll have to add a setter to the property.

Answer (score 1):

"What exactly happens when `aClass = null` called?": `aClass` becomes `null`, and object refered by `aClass` before becomes eligible for GC if it was the last reference to the object (but that is implicit effect - there is no "mark for GC now" behavior).

There is no way for object to know when it *becomes* eligible for GC (as it is implicit action) or whether a reference to instance was changed to null/other object. So there is no way to "guarantee that oParams becomes null after I assign null to the aClass".

Answer (score 1):

When `aClass = null` is called it now is a null reference. It doesn't change oParams. In C# there is no need to set objects to null after use for disposal.

In this case it's best to wrap the code in a using state.

```
using (var aClass = new AClass()){
   var oParams = aClass.Parameters;
   //do stuff
};//object is disposed
```

If you wrap your code in a `try..finally`, or, a `using()` block) the finaliser method on the object should call `Dispose()` for you.

A good resource on memory management in C# can be found here:
http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/04/28/foundations-of-programming-pt-7-back-to-basics-memory/